# p5.js Array: Multiple Objects getting Spliced instead of Single

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, p5.js, splice

I'm trying to create a moving array of decorative circles, and as soon as a circle moves off the edge of the screen I would like to remove it from the array. I have tried both splicing and filtering from the array – however, as soon as I do this, *all* the circles in the array get deleted, instead of just the intended one. Checked multiple sources and tried different thinkgs but I simply can't figure out what's going wrong. You can have a look at the demo here in the p5.js editor: https://editor.p5js.org/devalladares/sketches/v6bWAiISM

Main code here if it helps:

```
function setup() {

   //Create new Circle
   for (let i = 0; i < circleNumber; i++) {
     circles.push(new createCircle())
   }
 }

 function draw() {

   for (let i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

     circles[i].update(i * 200)

     //This is the problem: Simply cannot figure it out

     //Splicing

     if (circles[i].isDead()) {
       circles.splice(i, 1)
     }
   }

   //Filtering
   // circles = circles.filter(x => !x.isDead())
 }

//Class to create Circle

class createCircle {

   constructor() {
     this.circle = []
       this.origin = i * gap + emptySpace2
     this.pos = 0
     this.xPos = width / 5
     this.create()
   }

   create() {
     for (let i = 0; i < ringNumber; i++) {
       this.circle.push(new circleRing())
     }
   }

   update(dist) {

     push()
     this.xPos -= xSpeed
     this.pos = this.xPos + dist / 1.8

     translate(this.pos, this.origin / 1.15)
     scale(0.6, 0.6)

     for (let circles of this.circle) {
       circles.update()
     }
     pop()
   }

   isDead() {
     if (this.pos < 40) {
       return true;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
   }
 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't the most obvious thing in the world, but it comes from your for-loop and how you're updating your circles' x positions:

```
for (let i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     circles[i].update(i * 200)
```

When you delete a circle, the subsequent circles all shift down one index in your array, meaning if you delete the circle at index `0`, the circle at index 1 now becomes the circle at index 0, which when you apply your `cricles[i].update(i * 200)` in the next call to `draw()`, `i*200` will evaluate to `0`, which causes your circle to shift into the "kill zone".

Instead, you store an internal `circleNum` property in your circles when you create them, and adjust your position based on that:

```
class createCircle {
  constructor(circleNum) {
    this.circle = [];
    this.pos = 0;
    this.xPos = width / 5;
    this.circleNum = circleNum;
    this.create();
  }
  ...
}
```

Then when you create your circle, pass in the index:

```
//Create new Circle
for (let i = 0; i < circleNumber; i++) {
  circles.push(new createCircle(i))
}
```

also, change how you call `.update()`:

```
circles[i].update(200);
```

and lastly, use `circleNum` when calculating the new pos (as circleNum will remain consistent unlike `i`):

```
this.pos = this.xPos + (this.circleNum*dist) / 1.8;
```

Comment: Aaaaaaa oh my god thank you so much!!! Much love and gratitude and appreciation. Thank you!!!